# Trying to write a function with a loop and multiple SQLqueries

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, binding

The query that I am attempting to run is one that I usually just run in a straight SQL window (using PL/SQL developer) with the & to get the value prompted.

I want to write a function/program in PL/SQL that will pull a list of values from one query (also using this query in the for loop) and one by one run those values in a 2nd query, then return those values and output them.

I think that I am close, but keep getting the not all variables are bound error.  Am I not declaring variables correctly?

When I run the code and comment out the function get_case_count and the function call, it runs just fine.

Here is the code (updated with suggestion from answer 1):

```
declare 
skunumber integer;
scounter integer;

function get_case_count (skunum integer)
  return integer
  is

  numcases integer := 0;
begin
dbms_output.put_line('before SQL');  

select total - (tcaseacp - sum(pickamt)-numlockstock-numlockloc-numlostcase-numqdcase-qainvreserve)- sum(pickamt) - sum(scratched) - sum(filled) into numcases
from 
(select SKU, dscr,  requant total,   (retreserved+preres) pickamt, fulfilled filled,
     case when trays is null then 0 else trays end trays,
     case when reasoncode is null then 0 else (requested - retreserved - fulfilled - preres) end scratched,
      case when totcasesacp is null then 0 else totcasesacp end tcaseacp,
      case when numlockstock is null then 0 else numlockstock end numlockstock,
      case when numlockloc is null then 0 else numlockloc end numlockloc,
     case when totcaserec is null then 0 else totcaserec end totcaserec,
     case when totcasetr is null then 0 else totcasetr end totcasetr,
     case when numlostcase is null then 0 else numlostcase end numlostcase,
     case when numqdcase is null then 0 else numqdcase end numqdcase,
     case when qainvreserve is null then 0 else qainvreserve end qainvreserve
      from         

      (select    mat.externalidentifier SKU, mat.description dscr,   rol.requestedquantity requested,
                   rol.fulfilledquantity fulfilled,
                   case when resamount is null then   0  else  resamount  end retreserved,
                   case when quant is null then   0 else  quant  end preres,
                   rol.reasoncode reasoncode                       
              from ant.wmsretrievalorderline rol
              join ant.wmsretrievalorder ro
                on rol.retrievalorder_id = ro.id
              join ant.wmsmaterial mat
                on rol.material_id = mat.id
              left join (select res.retrievalorderline_id roid,
                               count(res.amount) resamount
                          from ant.wmsreservation res
                         group by res.retrievalorderline_id)
                on roid = rol.id
              left join (select preres.retrievalorderline_id rid,
                               sum(preres.prereservedquantity) quant
                          from ant.wmsretrievalprereservation preres
                          group by preres.retrievalorderline_id)
                on rid = rol.id
             where ro.retrievalstate in (4,6,10) 

            ) retrievalreserved
             right join (select m.externalidentifier SKUS,
                       sum(rl.requestedquantity) requant
                  from ant.wmsretrievalorderline rl
                  join ant.wmsmaterial m
                    on rl.material_id = m.id
                  group by m.externalidentifier) requested
                 on SKUS = SKU
              left join
              (select mat.externalidentifier SKURES, sum(res.amount) qainvreserve from ant.wmsreservation res
              join ant.wmsstockitem si
              on res.stockitem_id = si.id
              join ant.wmsmaterial mat
              on mat.id = si.material_id
              where res.retrievalorderline_id is null
              group by mat.externalidentifier)
              on SKU = SKURES                         
             left join
      (select mat.externalidentifier SKUC, sum(s.amount) totcasesacp
         from ant.wmsstockitem s
         join ant.wmsmaterial mat
           on s.material_id = mat.id
           join ant.wmsloadunit lu
           on s.loadunit_id = lu.id
           where s.owner = 0
           and substr(lu.barcode,1,2) != 'CA'
        group by mat.externalidentifier)totcases
        on SKUC = SKU
        left join
        (select mat.externalidentifier SKUT, count(si.loadunit_id) trays from ant.wmsstockitem si 
                join ant.wmsloadunit lu on
                lu.id = si.loadunit_id
                join ant.wmsmaterial mat on
                si.material_id = mat.id
            where lu.loadunittype_id = '6008' and si.owner = '0'
            group by mat.externalidentifier
          )numtrays
          on SKUT = SKU
         left join
         (select SKUBB, sum(qdnostock) numqdcase, sum(expstock) numexpcase
         from(select SKUBB, case when inwindow = 'no' then namt+n3amt else 0 end qdnostock,
         case when expired = 'yes' then amt else 0 end expstock
         from(select SKUBB, case when (bbd < sysdate and (qdwin < '999') and sg != 'GOCCaustic') then 'yes' else 'no' end expired,
          nvl(substr(bbd-nbbd, 7, 4), 0) datediff,case when substr(bbd-nbbd, 7, 4) > qdwin then 'no' else 'yes' end inwindow, 
           amt, nvl(namt, 0)namt, nvl(n3amt, 0) n3amt from
           (select mat.externalidentifier SKUBB, qdwin, sg, si.bestbeforedate bbd, lead(si.bestbeforedate, 1) over (order by si.bestbeforedate asc) nbbd,
           sum(si.amount) amt, lead(sum(si.amount), 1) over (order by si.bestbeforedate) namt, lead(sum(si.amount),2) over (order by si.bestbeforedate) n3amt
           from ant.wmsstockitem si
           join ant.wmsmaterial mat
           on si.material_id = mat.id
           join ant.wmsloadunit lu
           on si.loadunit_id = lu.id
           left join
           (select  distinct(rol.qdwindow) qdwin, mat.externalidentifier SKUQD, rol.shippinggroup sg
           from ant.wmsretrievalorderline rol 
           join ant.wmsmaterial mat
           on mat.id = rol.material_id

           )
           on SKUQD=mat.externalidentifier
           where lu.loadunittype_id = '6008'
           and si.owner = '0'
           and mat.externalidentifier = skunum
           group by mat.externalidentifier, qdwin, sg, si.bestbeforedate)
           where substr(bbd-nbbd, 7, 4) is not null
           ))group by SKUBB)
         on SKUBB = SKU
         left join 
         (select mat.externalidentifier SKUL, sum(s.amount) numlockstock
         from ant.wmsstockitem s
         join ant.wmsmaterial mat
           on s.material_id = mat.id
           join ant.wmsloadunit lu
           on s.loadunit_id = lu.id
           join ant.wmslocation l
           on lu.location_id = l.id
           where s.owner = 0
           and substr(l.name, 1, 2) in ('TS','CW')
           and s.id in (select distinct ll.stockitem_id sid from
           ant.wmslogisticlock ll where ll.logisticlockreason != '125')
        group by mat.externalidentifier
        order by SKUL)lockedstock
        on SKUL = SKU
        left join
        (select mat.externalidentifier SKULL, sum(s.amount) numlockloc
         from ant.wmsstockitem s
         join ant.wmsmaterial mat
           on s.material_id = mat.id
           join ant.wmsloadunit lu
           on s.loadunit_id = lu.id
           join ant.wmslocation l
           on lu.location_id = l.id
           where s.owner = 0
           and substr(l.name, 1, 2) in ('TS','CW')
           and (l.id in 
           (select fa.wmslocation_id from ant.failoverlock flk
           join ant.failoverarea fa
           on flk.failoverarea_id = fa.id)
           or lu.barcode in 
           (select tu.name from ant.mfstransportunit tu
            join ant.mfsstoragelocation sl on tu.storagelocation_id = sl.id
            where sl.id in (select mfsl.storagelocation_id 
            from ant.mfslogisticlock mfsl)))
           group by mat.externalidentifier)lockedloc
        on SKULL = SKU
        left join 
        (select mat.externalidentifier SKUR, sum(s.amount) totcaserec
         from ant.wmsstockitem s
         join ant.wmsmaterial mat
          on s.material_id = mat.id
          join ant.wmsloadunit lu
          on s.loadunit_id = lu.id
          join ant.wmslocation l
          on lu.location_id = l.id
           where s.owner = 0
           and substr(l.name, 1, 2) not in ('TS','CW', 'Ou')
           and substr(l.name, 1, 6) != 'LOC_PP'
           and l.name != 'LOC_GEN_LOST'
           and lu.barcode like '____________________'
        group by mat.externalidentifier
        )
        on SKUR=SKU
        left join
        (select mat.externalidentifier SKUTFR, sum(s.amount) totcasetr
         from ant.wmsstockitem s
         join ant.wmsmaterial mat
          on s.material_id = mat.id
          join ant.wmsloadunit lu
          on s.loadunit_id = lu.id
          join ant.wmslocation l
          on lu.location_id = l.id
          left join ant.wmslogisticlock ll
          on ll.stockitem_id = s.id
           where s.owner = 0
           and substr(l.name, 1, 2) not in ('TS','CW', 'Ou')
           and substr(l.name, 1, 6) != 'LOC_PP'
           and l.name != 'LOC_GEN_LOST'
           and lu.barcode like '________'
           and ll.logisticlockreason = 'Initial Putaway lock for inbound'
        group by mat.externalidentifier
        )
        on SKUTFR = SKU
        left join
        (select mat.externalidentifier SKULO, sum(s.amount) numlostcase
         from ant.wmsstockitem s
         join ant.wmsmaterial mat
           on s.material_id = mat.id
           join ant.wmsloadunit lu
           on s.loadunit_id = lu.id
           join ant.wmslocation l
           on lu.location_id = l.id
           where s.owner = 0
           and l.name = 'LOC_GEN_LOST'
           group by mat.externalidentifier
           order by SKULO)lostcases
        on SKULO = SKU
        where SKU is not null
        )
        where SKU = skunum
        group by SKU,dscr, total, tcaseacp, totcaserec,totcasetr,trays, numlockstock,numlockloc, numlostcase, numqdcase,qainvreserve;

dbms_output.put_line('After SQL');

return numcases;
end;  

begin
skunumber := 000000;
scounter := 0;

for skutable in
           (select mat.externalidentifier sku from ant.wmsstockitem si
            join ant.wmsmaterial mat
            on si.material_id = mat.id
            join ant.wmsloadunit lu
            on si.loadunit_id = lu.id
            join ant.wmslocation l
            on lu.location_id = l.id
            where l.name = 'CWL3156')

loop
skunumber := skutable.sku;
scounter := scounter+1;

dbms_output.put_line('sku number ' || scounter || ' is ' || skunumber);

dbms_output.put_line('cases needed for ' ||skunumber|| ' is '||get_case_count(skunumber));

end loop;

end;
```

It seems to be the skunum variable that is giving the issue, but again, I'm not sure what to do with that.  And if someone has a better suggestion for how to run this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

--UPDATE
I tried the first answer suggestion, and I rewrote my SQL and made the first line like this:

```
select total - (tcaseacp - sum(pickamt)-numlockstock-numlockloc-numlostcase-numqdcase-qainvreserve)- sum(pickamt) - sum(scratched) - sum(filled) into numcases
```

and now I get the ORA-01722: invalid number

all of the values in this math operation are numerical values.  Should I possibly try to put another select around this and then try the select .... into numcases?  I will update the code above with my new changes.

Comment: Adding a tag to identify the database product will help those with the correct expertise to notice your question, and save time for those who don't know that product. This looks like Oracle to me, so I've added that tag.

Comment: can't you just use select ... into numcases .... where SKU = skunumber instead of dynamic sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
execute immediate :query_str
   into :numcases
   using :skunum;
```

this means that query_str, numcases and skunum are bind variables, i.e. variables declared outside of PL/SQL (typically in SQL*Plus).

For PL/SQL variables you should simply write :

```
execute immediate query_str
   into numcases
   using skunum;
```

Also, in this case there's no need for dynamic SQL. So you can get rid of query_str and write your query directly :

```
select total ...   into numcases
   from ...
   where SKU = skunum
   group by ... ;
```

Comment: I tried this suggestion, but ran into another error, I edited my question above with the new code and the error.  thanks.

Comment: @saxman255 The invalid number can also be in the WHERE clause. Like `s.owner = 0` or `ro.retrievalstate in (4,6,10)`. You should probably check each subquery one by one.

Comment: Ah, found the problem with the number.  I forgot that my SKU value is actually a varchar or string in the DB :P so I just had to make my skunum variable a string and it ran great!  thanks!